# FormName.ButtonName.Visible = True - not working (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, multithreading

I am going to start by giving a simplified example of what I am dealing with

I have a windows form - lets call it 'formA' and on formA I have a button that in the properties for the button i set visible = false.
 I have a different class called MainLoop

```
Public class MainLoop


 sub new()
 end sub

 public sub run()
       If someCondition then
           formA.ButtonName.Visible = True
       End if


 end sub
 end class
```

I have more than one thread running in this application and one thread just keeps running through this 'public sub run' looping through it until certain conditions are met. By debugging and stepping through the application I am sure that it is running the line that sets the visiblity = true. But the buttons are just not showing up on my form. I have confirmed that its not a simple spelling mistake or anything - it seems I am missing a fundamental piece of logic here.

I have tried doing

```
dim TempForm as new formA
```

then in the IF statement I tried

```
 TempForm.ButtonName.Visible = true
```

but that is creating a new instance of the form - and its not actually setting the current form that I'm using's button.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use a *type name* where an *object variable* is required is a horrible vb.net trap.  That never fails to byte when you use threads, it gives you a new form object.  Using TempForm is an attempt at a workaround but falls in the **exact** same trap, you don't want to change the visibility of a button on a new form instance.  You need the one that the user is looking at.  Get ahead by stopping to try to update UI from a thread.  BackgroundWorker is the boilerplate class to keep you out of trouble like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who is wondering the answer ended up being,

Control.Invoke Method (Delegate, Object())

Tutorial can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If you are setting the visibility on a thread other than the UI thread, you will have to invoke it in order to make it visible.  You can't touch anything on the UI thread from another thread.